# trouble to sending the bearer token with fetch and axios

Tags: axios, fetch, expo, multipartform-data, bearer-token

I'm having problems with the token in the two alternatives I tried

```
uploadAttachment: async (file, id) => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    let params = { sale: id };

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    try {
      const req = await fetch(`${BASE_API}/sales/upload-attachment`, formData, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: token,
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },

      });

      /* console.log('que que ta dando' + JSON.stringify(req)); */

      //const json = await req.json();
      //return json;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return err.error;
    }
  },



uploadAttachment: async (file, id) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
  let params = { sale: id };

  let data = new FormData();
  data.append("file", file, file.name);

  try {
    let result = await axios.post(`${BASE_API}/sales/upload-attachment`, {
      data,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `${token}`,
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.response);
  }
};
```

The two codes are not able to pass the token to the api, this api is working normally because the web part is ok, but on mobile I am facing problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formats in this way,

for `fetch`

```
uploadAttachment: async (file, id) => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    let params = { sale: id };

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);//here should be file object
    try {
       const req = await fetch(`${BASE_API}/sales/upload-attachment`, {
             method: 'POST',
             headers: {
               Authorization: token,
               'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
             },
             body : formData
       });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err.error;
    }


}
```

for `axios`

```
uploadAttachment: async (file, id) => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    let params = { sale: id };

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);//here should be file object
    try {
       const req = await axios.post(`${BASE_API}/sales/upload-attachment`, formData, {
             headers: {
               Authorization: token,
               "Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data",
               'Accept': 'application/json',
             }
       });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err.error;
    }


}
```

Comment: The problem was not in either case but in the react native version, uploading files passed by post are having problems in the most recent versions of react native, the alternative I used was to revert the expo sdk to 40